# Convert '*' and '_' HTML using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am in middle of writing a script in Haskell that can convert text file as an input to output into HTML format. The first 4 guards in the below code is completely working fine which handle single and double '*' and '_' of the beginning of the list. The remaining guards that handle the last and the tail of the list they are compiled but they are not affect the output. A word surrounded by single underscores, `_hi_` or single asterisks, `*hi*` gets turned into an emphasis tag
A word surrounded by double underscores, `__hi__` or double asterisks, `**hi**` gets turned into a strong tag.

please give my code a look and I am waiting for your feedback in another solution that can make it change the output:

```
wordReplacer :: String -> String 

wordReplacer [] = []

wordReplacer (x:xs) 

          | x == '*' && x == last  xs  == "<strong>" ++  (wordReplacer $ init $ xs)++ "</strong>"
          | x == '_' && x == last  xs  == "<strong>" ++  (wordReplacer $ init $ xs)++ "</strong>" 
          | x == '*'  && x == head xs = "<strong>" ++ ( wordReplacer $ tail xs) ++ "</strong>"
          | x == '_'  && x == head xs = "<strong>" ++ (wordReplacer $ tail xs) ++ "</strong>"
          | x == '_' = "<em>" ++ wordReplacer xs ++ "</em>"
          | x == '*' = "<em>" ++ wordReplacer xs ++ "</em>"
          | x == '*' = "<em>"  ++ (wordReplacer $ init $ xs) ++ "</em>"
          | x == '_' = "<em>"  ++ (wordReplacer $ init $ xs) ++ "</em>"
          | otherwise  = char2Tag (x:xs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the guards matter. Also, the first 4 guards already match all the cases you mention. Rearranging the order should work for at least guard 5 and 6 (move to the top). Not sure what you want to achieve with guard 7 and 8? They will never be matched because of guard 4.

Comment: Yes the first four already match the only cases for the head of the list is and the other do not match the tail of the list. In the lat line I put '*' instead of '_' however I did correct it but same result. I also did change 5 and 6 to the top but it is still same.

Comment: I updated my code as you advised me, my updated code is above and it gives me this error: parse error on input `|'

Comment: There must be a `=` in every guard. Change the last `==` to `=` in the first two guards.